# What is the procedure to test cypress-cucumber tests to run on multiple browsers

Tags: automation, cypress

I am new to Cypress, I have tests ready running on cypress gui, but now want to automate these tests running on multiple browsers. Can I get help running my tests in multiple browsers.

I have my tests written in feature files and step definitions

Comment: You want to run Cypress on multiple browsers simultaneously?

Comment: yes please, I can run the test from selected browser from command line but now want to know how to set the configs to run them on selected browsers when running these tests on virtual machines

Comment: Cypress 4.9.0 had issues in handling firefox browser popup, which was mentioned as got a fix in Cypress 5.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked docs? You can prepare cli commands with desired browsers and run them all. Or as separate processes.

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/launching-browsers.html#Browsers